# How to get the HTML from a website in react.js

Tags: reactjs, axios, fetch, screen-scraping

i just want to get the plain html of a website in a variable. Let's say google.com but when i try to do this i get cors errors. Is there any simple way to complete this task ?  i just want a return that says hey google.com is exists status code is 200 and here is the html from that page

I just want to get the html like a browser, that simple , but people saying things like you need your own proxy server to reach 3rd party server, I tried lot's of params with axios and fetch , After some search i used various scrapers but the result was the same , i just want a return that says hey google.com is exists status code is 200 and here is the html from that page , how can i do this simply , i dont have too much experience in node.js and react.

Comment: Not as familiar with those languages, but from my experience of doing this with ASP CLASSIC, you MUST encode that data you are pulling, because of all the infinite possibilities of characters combinations that might error out due to not being terminated and other such things.

Answer (score 0):

There is a library on NPM that could be for you.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/scrape-html-web